# Tablesorter How to update table header values

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, tablesorter, tableheader

I am using Motties tablesorter table, which works like a charm. Now I need to update the column headers dynamically and optionally the tables contents. Update the content works fine.  How I would update the table header text of a tablesorter table ?
This is how I update the table2 contents:

```
var $table = $('#table2');
$.tablesorter.clearTableBody( $table[0] );
$("#table2 tbody").append(data);
var resort = true;
$("#table2").trigger("update", [resort]);
```

How would I update the table header only ?
I thought I could do this way :

```
var headers= ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
$('table2 thead').html('<tr>' + headers + '</tr>');
```

but it does only append a new header on top of the header line.

Update:
OK here is what I did so far to update the header completely:

```
var hdr = new Array("Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango");
var i =0;
$("#table2 thead th").each(function () {
$(this).text(hdr[i])
i++;
})
```

Comment: i forgot to mention that i want to update the existing header of course

Answer (score 1):

If you're updating the headers only to change the content of the header, then use [`updateHeaders`](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#updateheaders).

If you're adding or removing columns, use [`updateAll`](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#updateall); but this method has proven to be unreliable if overly used. The best solution in this case would be to [`destroy`](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#destroy) the tablesorter instance and re-initialize it.

Comment: Thank you Mottie, I saw that example(updateHeaders) but how do(!) I set new values (individually per column) for the header texts ?

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're trying to do. New values per column? Do you mean you update the text only?

Comment: yes I just want to update the text. Actually I really wanted to update the complete table including headers after I got data back from an ajax call. I was successful so far to Update the table rows and columns with the apend code above. But I also need to update the column headers with new text.

Comment: I am not the query expert :-/

Answer (score 0):

That would be the answer to update all column headers.
The combination 'thead th' was solution to update the correct header.

```
var hdr = new Array("Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango");
var i =0;
$("#table2 thead th").each(function () {
$(this).text(hdr[i])
i++;
})
```